# Using a pattern for making a list

Tags: python, list, function

I'm trying to make a function that will make a list based on a pattern depending on the length of another list. I'm not sure how to do this due to the nature of the pattern. I'm trying to make something like that will behave like:

```
len(a_list) = 50

created_pattern_a_list = [1,2,4,8,10,20,40]

len(b_list) = 9000

created_patten_b_list = [1,2,4,8,10,20,40,80,100,200,400,800,1000,2000,4000,8000]
```

So the pattern I want is 1,2,4,8,10,... .So it is exponential but only until it at the next power of 10, then it starts over at that power of 10. I'm not sure of a way to make a function that could do this. Something like:

```
def create_patten_list(a_list):
    reff_list = [1,2,4,8,10,20,40,80,100,200,400,800,1000,2000,4000,8000,10000]
    corr_list = [a for a in reff_list if a <= len(a_list)]
    return corr_list
```

But the length of a_list might be much longer than 10000, so I can't just use a default list of a set length like this. Is there a better way to set a pattern like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure this isn't the most elegant solution, but consider this:
The repeating part of your template is only 1, 2, 4, and 8.  The rest is just order of magnitude.

```
def get_pattern(length):
    template = [1, 2, 4, 8]
    output = []
    i = 0
    while True:
        num = template[i%4] * 10**(i//4)
        if num > length:
            break
        output += [num]
        i += 1
    return output
```

So:

```
>>> get_pattern(5000)
[1, 2, 4, 8, 10, 20, 40, 80, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1000, 2000, 4000]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
from itertools import cycle
def get_pattern(n):
    for e,i in enumerate(cycle((1,2,4,8))):
        val = i*(10**(e//4))
        if val > n: return
        yield val
```

so

```
>>>list(get_pattern(5000)) # or len(a_list) instead of 5000
[1, 2, 4, 8, 10, 20, 40, 80, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1000, 2000, 4000]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def create_pattern_list(a_list):
    def gen(n):
        num = 1
        step = 10
        while num <= n:
            yield num
            num = num * 2
            if num / step:
                num = step
                step = step * 10

    return list(gen(len(a_list)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enjoy abusing `itertools`, you can use this solution.

```
from itertools import count, repeat, cycle, izip
def get_pattern(length):
    repeated_multiplier = (y for x in count(0) for y in repeat(x, 4))
    repeat_1248 = cycle([1, 2, 4, 8])
    number_generator = izip(repeat_1248, repeated_multiplier)
    values = []
    while True:
        x = next(number_generator)
        x = x[0] * 10**x[1]
        if x > length:
            break
        values.append(x)
    return values
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you the results you need:

```
from itertools import takewhile, cycle

def create_patten_list(a_list):
    length = len(a_list)
    sequence = [1,2,4,8]
    return [x[1] * 10 ** (x[0] // 4) for x in takewhile(lambda x: x[1] * 10 ** (x[0] // 4) <= length, enumerate(cycle(sequence)))]

print create_patten_list(range(50))
print create_patten_list(range(9000))
```

Giving the following output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, 10, 20, 40]
[1, 2, 4, 8, 10, 20, 40, 80, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000]
```